# Устранение погрешности при расчете времени

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, инспекция-кода

Есть задача - устранение погрешности времени окончания рабочего дня.

Я решил ее довольно криво с костылями, очень хотелось бы увидеть пример хорошего решения, мой код ниже, и вот постановка задачи:

> У работников есть 3 смены по 8 часов: с 00:00 до 8:00 - 1 смена, с
>   8:00 до 16:00 - вторая смена, с 16:00 до начала следующих суток -
>   третья смена. При этом работники заканчивают смену чуть позже на
>   неизвестное время, но не больше размера одной смены (Или 8-ми часов).
>   Одиному работнику подряд преднозначено работать только одну смену.
>
> В качестве входящего параметра известен номер смены 1 или 2 или 3.
>
> Нужно написать функцию которая будет в случае если работник
>   переработал и "залез" на чужую смену будет возвращать дату и время
>   последней секунды предыдущей смены вместо реального времени окончания.
>
> Пример:
>
> Работник смены №1 сдал задание 1 мая 2018г 8:30, функция должна
>   вернуть 1 мая 2018г 7:59. В случаях неточностей при переходе с 3й
>   смены к 1й дата должна учитываться.

Вот мое решение:

```
function computeLastUpdate(shiftNumber) {
    let lastUpdate = new Date();

    const beforeMidnight = new Date(lastUpdate.getFullYear(), lastUpdate.getMonth(), lastUpdate.getDate(), 23, 59, 59);
    const afterMidnight = new Date(lastUpdate.getFullYear(), lastUpdate.getMonth(), lastUpdate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0);
    const eightAM = new Date(lastUpdate.getFullYear(), lastUpdate.getMonth(), lastUpdate.getDate(), 8, 0, 0);
    const fourPM = new Date(lastUpdate.getFullYear(), lastUpdate.getMonth(), lastUpdate.getDate(), 16, 0, 0);

    if (shiftNumber === 1 && lastUpdate > eightAM && lastUpdate < fourPM) {

        lastUpdate = new Date(lastUpdate.getFullYear(), lastUpdate.getMonth(), lastUpdate.getDate(), 7, 59, 59);

    } else if (shiftNumber === 2 && lastUpdate > fourPM && lastUpdate < beforeMidnight) {

        lastUpdate = new Date(lastUpdate.getFullYear(), lastUpdate.getMonth(), lastUpdate.getDate(), 15, 59, 59);

    } else if (shiftNumber === 3 && lastUpdate > afterMidnight && lastUpdate < eightAM) {

        lastUpdate = new Date(lastUpdate.getFullYear(), lastUpdate.getMonth(), lastUpdate.getDate() - 1, 23, 59, 59);

    }

    return lastUpdate;
}
```

Кажется очень громоздко и формулировка `с 16:00 до начала следующих суток` как-то сбиват. В общем, нельзя ли как-то поэлегантнее это решить?

Comment: Возник вопрос: а что, если передать функции shiftNumber равный 1 в то время как сейчас 18:00, например? Ваш код не войдет ни в один if и просто вернет текущие дату и время.

Comment: @Misha Saidov мне кажется что это условия задачи и не подразумевает, хотя не уверен, но да тогда код сработает не правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тогда можно уложиться в такой вот код. Это менее читабельно, чем ваш пример, но работает стабильно

```
function computeLastUpdate(shiftNumber) {
   let today = new Date(); //тут понятно
   let mustEndHours = shiftNumber * 8 - 1; //час, в который должна была закончится предыдущая смена
   today = (mustEndHours === 23 ? new Date(today - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) : today); //если это третья смена, то вычесть из сегодняшнего 1 день
   return new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), mustEndHours, 59, 59);
}
```

Также буду рад, если сообщество исправит потенциальные недочеты моего примера.